# The rgb values are being automatically disturbed after encoding

Tags: java, rgb

I am building an encoder where i am uploading an image, then i take its first pixel that is the pixel at the position (0,0). i extract its blue component and reset its value different from the original value.
Now when i try to check the value that i reset, the value does not match
for eg: if the value was initially 120 and i reset it to 49, when i check the value it gives 111 which is incorrect...can anyone help?
image is stored in p1;

in the encoder

```
String e="00110001";
int bi= Integer.parseInt(e,2);
int r=p1.get(0,0).getRed();
int g=p1.get(0,0).getGreen();
Color clr= new Color(r,g,bi);
p1.set(0,0,clr);
```

now i save this image

in the decoder i upload my saved image p11

```
int pp=p11.get(0,0).getBlue();
```

pp and bi do not match
please help

code for set and get

```
public Color get(int x, int y) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= width())  throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("x must be between 0 and " + (width()-1));
    if (y < 0 || y >= height()) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("y must be between 0 and " + (height()-1));
    if (isOriginUpperLeft) return new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
    else                   return new Color(image.getRGB(x, height - y - 1));
}


public void set(int x, int y, Color color) {
    if (x < 0 || x >= width())  throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("x must be between 0 and " + (width()-1));
    if (y < 0 || y >= height()) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("y must be between 0 and " + (height()-1));
    if (color == null) throw new NullPointerException("can't set Color to null");
    if (isOriginUpperLeft) image.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());
    else                   image.setRGB(x, height - y - 1, color.getRGB());
}
```

Comment: why don't you use you `clr` object in `p1.set`?

Comment: what is `p1`'s type ?

Comment: @Trichoko it was a tyoing error..i corrected it. Thank you. the problem remains

Comment: p1's type is picture...which is  a class i have created to store images

Comment: Not enough information here. What is p1 and can you show the code for p1.set(int,int,Color) and p1.get(int,int)?

Comment: @jarmod here is the code you asked for. However i have figured out that there is some problem with the way i am saving it. can anyone suggest how should i save the image after editing my rgb values

Comment: which format do use for saving your image? A destructive format like jpeg or something like bmp or png?

Comment: @StephaneM thank you. i was using jpg. Now i changed to png and its done. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You seem to have both a method named height() and a member variable named height, and you use them interchangeably in your set/get methods.